# Get WCF webservice response as XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a simple WCF web service. How can I view it's response as XML?

Do I create a consuming client application and then output the results as XML somehow?

Comment: You mean viewing the response just for debugging?

Comment: @Aliostad the service takes data from the database. I want to be able to provide the xml to someone for quality control before we pass it over to the client

Comment: WCF abstract away all of this. You could have the binding so that data is passed as binary, binary XML or completely propriety format such as in NetTcp or NetNamedPipe. I suggest you use Fiddler to get the data as it travels acorss the wire - but only you are using a binding which ouputs plain XML format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rather recommend you to use [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/simpledownload2c.html?gclid=CJeFgKGEr64CFSgntAod9m4oSA%20), as it provides good view of WSDL, SOAP, xsd.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Wcf testing tool provided to you by visual studio. Its pretty straight forward to use.

You can find it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient

Answer (score 1):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) might be useful for you. Will also help you to test your service. Point it at the WSDL and away you go.

Answer (score 1):

You may use WCF tracing utility - SvcTraceViewer.exe. Just configure tracer in your config file.

Take a look at this source(at the bottom, system.diagnostics section):

http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/068ddfd6bf36#trunk%2fSrc%2fHst%2fIisHost%2fWeb.config

This is how we use WCF tracing in our project.

Answer (score 0):

Below are all the things I'd suggest:

- Enable tracing on the service side, generate tracing logs, and analyze with SvcTraceViewer. To do this, follow the instructions at [this MSDN article on using the service trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx).
- Turn on debug exceptions. This is done by turning in includeExceptionDetailInFaults, which [you can do by following the instructions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/david_bennett/archive/2006/11/12/how-to-turn-on-debug-exceptions-with-wcf.aspx).
- Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor the wire traffic.

Try this, and please report back! :)